# sql subtraction on two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables, common column is `truck_id`.
I need to subtract two tables from each other to find the net amount.
The result I want:

| truck_id | difference |
| --- | --- |
| 35kd85 | 1500 |
| 35hh52 | 900 |

```
SELECT

(SELECT SUM(last_revenue) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT last_revenue FROM 
    Expedition WHERE YEAR(departure_date) > 2020 AND truck_id = '31adc444'
    UNION ALL SELECT last_revenue FROM 
      ChainingExpedition WHERE YEAR(departure_date) > 2020 AND truck_id = '31adc444'
    )x 
    )-(SELECT SUM(price_dollar) FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT price_dollar FROM TruckMaintenanceExpense
        WHERE YEAR(payment_date) > 2020 AND expense_type = 'çeker' 
          AND truck_id ='31adc444'
      )x 
    ) AS difference
```

SQL subtraction on two different tables
When I type `truck_id` in my query, I get the right result, but my goal is to draw as a list.

Comment: You need to show sample data from the two source tables. Showing us the output of your script isn't helpful on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I would create a list of all trucks that meet the criteria you are looking for. Then, I'll get a list of all trucks with revenue and a separate list of trucks with expense. Then you join those 3 tables together and do the math. You query was very hard to follow without good indenting and structure. Next time you ask a question, be sure to include sample data. You should be writing all the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements that I include in the `EXAMPLE DATA` section in the fiddle below.

```
--*****EXAMPLE DATA*****
CREATE TABLE Expedition (
  truck_id nvarchar(50)
  , last_revenue decimal(19,2)
  , departure_date datetime
);

CREATE TABLE TruckMaintenanceExpense (
  truck_id nvarchar(50)
  , price_dollar decimal(19,2)
  , payment_date datetime
);

INSERT INTO Expedition (truck_id, last_revenue, departure_date)
VALUES ('35kd85', 2000.00, '2020-1-1')
  , ('35kd85', 3500.00, '2020-1-1')
  , ('35hh52', 300.00, '2020-1-1')
  , ('35hh52', 258.98, '2020-1-1')
;

INSERT INTO TruckMaintenanceExpense (truck_id, price_dollar, payment_date)
VALUES ('35kd85', 9865.23, '2020-2-1')
  , ('35kd85', 321.54, '2020-2-1')
  , ('35hh52', 159.78, '2020-2-1')
  , ('35hh52', 598.77, '2020-2-1')
;
--*****END EXAMPLE DATA*****

--Create a list of all truck_ids. It would be more helpful
--if you had a table that defined all the trucks (i.e. dbo.trucks).
WITH AllTrucks as (
  SELECT truck_id
  FROM TruckMaintenanceExpense
  
  UNION ALL 

  SELECT truck_id
  FROM Expedition
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  a.truck_id

  --Use ISNULL to make sure we have 0.00 if the truck is missing
  --either revenue or expense.
  , ISNULL(tRev.total_revenue,0) - ISNULL(tExp.total_expense,0) as difference

--Get the list of truck_ids. Use SELECT DISTINCT to elimiate duplicates.
FROM AllTrucks as a

  --Get a list of all trucks with Expedition reveue.
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      e.truck_id
      , YEAR(e.departure_date) as [year]
      , SUM(e.last_revenue) as total_revenue
    FROM Expedition as e
    WHERE e.departure_date >= '2020-1-1 00:00:00'
      AND e.departure_date < '2021-1-1 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY e.truck_id, YEAR(departure_date)
  ) as tRev
    ON tRev.truck_id = a.truck_id
  
  --Get a list of all trucks with maintenance expenses.
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      tme.truck_id
      , YEAR(tme.payment_date) as [year]
      , SUM(tme.price_dollar) as total_expense
    FROM TruckMaintenanceExpense as tme
    WHERE tme.payment_date >= '2020-1-1 00:00:00'
      AND tme.payment_date < '2021-1-1 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY tme.truck_id, YEAR(payment_date)
  ) as tExp
    ON tExp.truck_id = a.truck_id
;
```

| truck_id | difference |
| --- | --- |
| 35hh52 | -199.57 |
| 35kd85 | -4686.77 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/20ArfvVF)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry for that, as it's my first question, I may have missed it. I have a table called truck and your query worked. You are great!